# Can't get 'mvn test' run the tests

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, automation, pom.xml

For some reason I don't know, sometimes, when I create a new Test project (I use IntelliJ + Maven module), I use the same pom file with some plugins which currently works in another projects, but then when I run the command line

```
mvn test
```

it doesn't run the JUnit test methods I have written. And I don't know what's wrong, it says:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building n26 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ n26 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ n26 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ n26 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Automation\NewHomePage\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ n26 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Automation\NewHomePage\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ n26 ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.713 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-24T13:02:50+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/306M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Normally, it will execute tests afterwards, but sometimes it stops here.

Comment: Are your test method annotated `@Test`?

Comment: the tests are executed by the surefire-plugin, it has a naming convention of the files it will interpret as test classes: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes - do your test classes match to them? otherwise you need to configure that.

Comment: @Tunaki, yes, my tests have annotation "@Test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@wemu thanks, I named my file was xxxTests.java, and the naming convention is xxxTest.java. It works, thanks